# Flexible Merge - two columns in one

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in about 50 sheets and structure for all of them are same. Please find data structure in an example below, in column May will be data and in next column letter for example "B" or "AB". I want to merge those two columns in one, so my data shold looks like 236AB. My code should work for all columns in sheets, because in some sheets I have 5 columns and in another 25. Anybody can help me with this one? Thank so much!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO where everythings made up and the points don't matter.  Please post code you have attempted, as this is not a "get-free-code" site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have attach code for your requirement, It will automatically search for May and June keyword and will perform concatenation for that particular columns alone.

```
Sub test()
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Dim monthss(12) As String

monthss(1) = "May"
monthss(2) = "June"
monthss(3) = "August"



    For Each Ws In wb.Worksheets

    For j = 1 To 3

With Ws.UsedRange
    Set c = .Find(monthss(j), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstrow = c.Row
        firstcol = c.Column
        End If
    End With

    Set c = Nothing
  lastrow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, firstcol).End(xlUp).Row


' For May Sheet
If firstrow > 0 Then

    For i = firstrow + 1 To lastrow
           Ws.Cells(i, firstcol).Value = Ws.Cells(i, firstcol).Value & Ws.Cells(i, firstcol + 1).Value
    Next

firstrow = 0
End If
' for June Sheet

Next j

Next Ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks as something that I need. I have an error on this line Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1"), I have tried to change sheet name but is not working. Is there are option for absolut sheets? Becase macro should apply for all my sheets in excel? I asume for all other month for exampe July and August I just have to copy/paste to code below and change the month name? Thank so much for your effort.

Comment: check your sheetname. and paste the macro where data is

Comment: Sorry you are right, its working good. How can I add more sheets and more columns?

Comment: use other month just like may and june i have used or loop it

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what your end goal is but could you not add a new column on the left and make it's formula be CONCATENATE(A1:E1) and make it go as far down the sheet as you need it?

Then if you need to afterwards you could copy paste values that column and delete the others.

All fairly quick to do even if recording in excel.
Do you want to give that a go and post back if you get stuck?

Comment: Concatenate is only for strings, and unfortunetly I need to have first column :( so my code should works like if letter is found in next column next to data merge them.

Comment: So solve by making it be text: =CONCATENATE(IF(ISNUMBER(B1),TEXT(B1,0),B1),IF(ISNUMBER(C1),TEXT(C1,0),C1),IF(ISNUMBER(D1),TEXT(D1,0),D1))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Function that merges 2 Columns together:

```
Function mergeColumns(mergeColumn As Integer)

Dim i As Integer

'Adjust startvalue(1)
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row Step 1

    'Combine mergeColumn and Column next to it
    Cells(i, mergeColumn).Value = Cells(i, mergeColumn).Value & Cells(i, mergeColumn + 1).Value

    'Clear the Content of the Cell next to Mergecolumn
    Cells(i, mergeColumn + 1).Value = ""
Next i
End Function
```

Lets say you want to merge column A and B, the call would be `mergeColumns 1`

Now work out a routine to find the right columns to merge.